# How to evaluate a boolean expression in C?

Tags: c, function, boolean, boolean-expression

I want to evaluate the following boolean expression in C:

```
f = (b+c')(a'+c')(a+b'+c)
```

This is my current program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a,b,c,f;
   a=0;b=1;c=1;   
   f=((b|(~c))&((~a)|(~c))&(a|(~b)|c));
   printf("%d\n",f);
}
```

The function should return 1 since a=0,b=1 and c=1 but it returns -1.
Also, when a=1,b=1 and c=1 it returns -2 instead of 0.

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: *Boolean* semantics in C is provided through operators `!`, `||` and `&&`. Operators `~`, `|` and `&` implement *bitwise* semantics, which is a completely different thing.

Comment: Note that C also has a boolean type, you don't have to use *int* if you want to make it explicit you are dealing with booleans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C you use `!` for negation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a,b,c,f;
   a=0;b=1;c=1;   
   f=((b||(!c))&&((!a)||(!c))&&(a||(!b)||c));
   printf("%d\n",f);
}
```

The `~` operator flips all the bits in a number, which is not what you wanted, and why you were getting -1.

Also you need `||` instead of `|` and `&&` instead of `&`. The `&` and `|` operators work on individual bits, where as the `||` and `&&` are logical operators and do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to get my required output with bitwise operators?

Comment: @kamoroso94 `f&1=((b|(~c))&((~a)|(~c))&(a|(~b)|c));` Like this?

Comment: @WhiteFlameAB No, more like this: `f = 1&( ((b|(~c))&((~a)|(~c))&(a|(~b)|c)) );`

Answer (score 4):

This is because you're using the so-called *bitwise operators*, which work separately on each bit of a number.

So assuming `int` is 32 bits, you have:

```
a    = 00000000000000000000000000000000
b    = 00000000000000000000000000000001
c    = 00000000000000000000000000000001
~c   = 11111111111111111111111111111110
b|~c = 11111111111111111111111111111111
```

and so on.

If you use the *logical operators* `&&`, `||` and `!` instead, then each number will be treated as a single "bit" (0 if it's 0, or 1 if it's not 0).

Alternatively, you could add `& 1` at the end to make sure all the bits except the last one are 0.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please elaborate on what you meant by adding &1 at the end?